# Can't create asp net core 2.0 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm having serious troubles in my Web Api project. I can't install entityframework nor update any of the updates to the project. Trying to update there gives me the error "package restore failed. rolling back package changes".

First of, I can't make a project with asp net core, only with the 1.1 version even though I have the correct version installed. See these two pictures.
[image]

[image]

As you can see it is installed.

When I try to update these:
[image]

I get this error:
[image]

Trying to install entity framework gives me: 
[image]

How can I upgrade my project to asp net core 2.0 or atleast make a new 2.0 project?

Comment: did you update visual studio to latest version ?

Comment: You should definitely see it in that dropdown once it's installed. The package you need though is "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" once you do get it installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for ASP.NET Core 2.0 was added in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 (see the original [accouncement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/)).

Your first error is due to the fact that ASP.NET Core 2.0 is not compatible with .NET Core 1.1. You'll need to target .NET Core 2.0 (`netcoreapp2.0`) for this, as you've attempted to do. Upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 will allow you to do that, as I mentioned above.

Your second error is due to the fact that Entity Framework 6.1.3 is not compatible with .NET Core 1.1 (or, in fact, any version of .NET Core). In order to use Entity Framework in a .NET Core project, you will instead need to use Entity Framework Core ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore)). This is an entirely new version of Entity Framework, so make sure you check out the [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

firstly check **dotNetCore** version

Open Command Prompt and run this `dotnet --version`

install `dotnetCore` framework lastest on [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

alternatively you can update the visual studio